# Check if array has a particular index in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, arrays, angularjs-scope

In AngularJS expressions, how can I check if an array has value in a particular index or not? Consider the following example

```
$scope.arr =['one','two','three'];
```

In HTML.

```
<p ng-show="arr[3]!=''">{{arr[3]}}</p>
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to compare with `undefined`.

```
<p ng-show="arr[3]!=undefined">{{arr[3]}}</p>
```

```js
function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.arr =['one','two','three'];
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
       <p ng-show="arr[2]!=undefined">{{arr[2]}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also, you can define a `function` which check if an array has value in a `particular` index, using `typeof` operator.

```
function isDefined(arrayElement) {
      return typeof arrayElement!== 'undefined';
}
```

```js
function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.arr =['one','two','three'];
  $scope.isDefined=function(arrayElement){
      return typeof arrayElement!== 'undefined';
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
       <p ng-show="isDefined(arr[3])">{{arr[3]}}</p>
       <p ng-show="!isDefined(arr[3])">undefined</p>
  </div>
</div>
```